# Official documentation for MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I think I found the official documentation at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514(v=VS.98).aspx
but that seems pretty useless compared to the blog posts from the developers and compared to other projects such as Zend Framework and Ruby on Rails.

I found the source code at aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781 where they are saying "For more details about ASP.NET MVC 3, please visit http://asp.net/mvc/mvc3" so is this the official place?

So where is the official documentation? Where can I find the api guide? Where can I find the Issue tracker?

(I was only allowed to send one hyperlink in this post since I am a new user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official API documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416515(v=VS.98).aspx

Tutorials here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Blogs here: http://www.google.com

Recommended book here: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040)

Comment: That's an MVC 1 book. Come on dude.

Comment: The "official" documentation is autogenerated - it does not explain anything. I think we are supposed to read the source code.

Comment: As @Jack , said, i read one of the comments of @ Darin Dimitrov , saying , that Darin looks at source code to see how mvc works, so my question is , a beginner after learning asp mvc tutorial,  should he check the documentation or sit and read the whole source before creating a project. Or can you suggest how you use documentation and source code ?, have you read the whole mvc source code ?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the release notes: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes.

Comment: No links are working for the new release. I tried known issues and some other links but I got an error page when clicking on them

Comment: Can you try again. I'm using Chrome 8 and the link perfectly opens for me.

Comment: I am getting the following error with IE, Firefox and Chrome when I click on any of the top links in the link you provided. "Sorry, an error has occurred...

Unfortunately an error has occurred during the processing of your page request. Please be assured we log and review all errors, even if you do not report this error we will endeavor to correct it."

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. It's a direct generic error page on that site itself. I've checked from home & work with different browsers and didn't get that error myself.